# AWS VPC - Access webapp running in private subnet through bastion host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-applications, cloud, amazon-vpc

I have this VPC architecture setup in AWS using Terraform:

1. 1 VPC for all environments with 1 Internet Gateway
2. VPC in one region
3. 3 Availability Zones with 1 private subnet and 1 public (utility) subnet for each (total of 6 subnets)
4. 3 NAT Gateways - one for each utility subnet with 3 Elastic IPs assigned to their network interfaces
5. 3 EIPs - each associated to network interface of public subnets
6. 1 Bastion Host (with Public IP associated) to allow SSH access to private EC2 instances
7. EC2 Instances (1 master and 1 node in each private subnet)
8. 1 Elastic Load Balancer across the 3 AZs with the instances within ELB referencing the 3 masters.

I can reach the EC2 instances by SSHing through the bastion host without any issues. I have a simple webapp deployed (let's say a webapp running in a docker container in port 5000) in one of these EC2 instances. Now how do I access this webapp running at port 5000 from my browser? Is it through the public IP of the bastion host? If yes, how does the port forwarding happen to the correct EC2 instance where the webapp is running?

Thanks for your help.

Abdul.

Answer (score 3):

To access it from your browser, you will have to do one of the following:

- Add the specific instance you would like to direct traffic to to your ELB. That is, remove the instances you do not want to access from the load balancer. This is not a secure option.
- Use [SSH port forwarding](https://solitum.net/posts/an-illustrated-guide-to-ssh-tunnels/) over your bastion to the instance, assuming the bastion can access the port on the web server. See the "Local tunnels" section. Your command will look something like this: `ssh -L 8080:your-webserver-ip:5000 ip-of-your-bastion -N`; then, in your browser, navigate to http://localhost:8080/
- Install an [OpenVPN appliance](https://docs.openvpn.net/getting-started/amazon-web-services-ec2-tiered-appliance-quick-start-guide/) to connect to your instances directly via VPN
- Make the instance public (move it into a public subnet) and assign it an EIP

Comment: Great thanks for those options. Appreciated. I will try out local tunnels first which suits me best. If that doesn't work out for some reason, I will go for the other options. Also I have 3 Elastic IPs assigned to the network interfaces of public subnets. Are they needed at all because I have a dedicated bastion host as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the utility subnet is a public subnet? If it is then you will need to deploy something there to direct the web traffic. Usually this is will be an elastic load balancer but you can deploy and EC2 instance running Nginx or Apache.

This will pass the traffic from the internet to the EC2 instance in the private subnet so you can browse the webapp.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have got an Elastic Load Balancer across the 3 Availability Zones (updated in my question now). May I know how I could direct traffic across the ELB to the webapp running in that specific EC2 instance?

Comment: So if you have an ELB then you can use the ELB DNS name, you can find this via the console. Look for the DNS name, you can then add on the port number to the DNS name (http:/loadbalancerDNSname:5000/  If you want to use a custom domain name then you will need to add that into Route53 or point the DNS records to the ASW ELB DNS name.

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyMagic. When I reach the ELB at port 5000, how does the ELB know which EC2 instance to forward the request to? I believe I should be running the webapp in all 3 node instances to handle failover and ELB will forward the request to any of those 3 instances? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The ELB will use round robin to distrubite the load to the EC2 instances, you can turn on Cookies/Sticky sessions on the ELB so that a user goes to the same back end EC2 each time. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Thanks for that tip. It's been a while - I have moved on to using Kubernetes pods and exposing services/ingress through which I access the specific apps deployed through helm. Thanks for all the help.